# Changing a icon in ActionBar depending on a condition

Tags: java, android, boolean, logic, android-actionbar

I am updating a record in a SQLite database when the user presses an icon on the `ActionBar`. The information being updated is a flag that adds a record to a Favourites page.

PROBLEM

When the user adds or removes the record to favourites, I would like the icon in the `ActionBar` to change. I have a full star icon and a empty star icon.

The `setIcon` method displays the the full star icon if the record is a favourite, and a empty star icon if the record is not a favourite.

In the code below you will see I am using a `boolean isInFavourite`, which is `true` when `String fav = "y"`.

When entering the `Activity`, the `icon` displayed is correct.

When the user clicks on the `icon` to invoke the `onMenuItemClick()` method, the record is successfully updated but the `icon` does not change.

I am unable to change the `boolean isInFavourite` when the record has been updated because Eclipse wants all the variables to be set as `final`

Can anyone help me change the icon to once the record has been updated.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    db = new DBHelper(this);
    db.createDataBase();
    db.openDataBase();


    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    final String rowid = bundle.getString("id");
    final String fav = bundle.getString("fav");

    //Boolean to check if record is a favourite
    final boolean isInFavourite = fav.contentEquals("y");

    menu.add("Add to Favourites")
            .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    String toggle;
                    String message;

                    //Logic to add or remove row from recording.
                    if (isInFavourite) {
                        toggle = "n";
                        message = "Recipe removed from Favourites";
                    } else {
                        toggle = "y";
                        message = "Recipe added to Favourites";
                    }

                    //Update favourite record in database
                    db.updateFavourite(rowid, toggle);
                    db.close();

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    return true;
                }

            })

            //Set icon depending on whether record is a favourite or not.
            .setIcon(isInFavourite ? R.drawable.fav_true : R.drawable.fav_false)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);

    return true;

}
```

Thanks to @dmon for the solution

SOLUTION

```
private DBHelper db = null;

public String fav = null;
public String rowid = null;
public boolean isFav;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ...

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    rowid = bundle.getString("id");
    fav = bundle.getString("fav");

    if (fav.contentEquals("y")) {
        isFav = true;
    } else {
        isFav = false;
    }


    try {
        db = new DBHelper(this);
        db.createDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_settings, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem fave = menu.findItem(R.id.add);
    MenuItem unfave = menu.findItem(R.id.remove);

    fave.setVisible(isFav);
    unfave.setVisible(!isFav);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
    case R.id.add:
        fav = "n";
        isFav = false;
        updateFav();
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        Toast("Removed from Favourites");
        return true;
    case R.id.remove:
        fav = "y";
        isFav = true;
        updateFav();
        supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        Toast("Added to Favourites");
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

public void updateFav (){
        db.openDataBase();
        db.updateFavourite(rowid, fav);
        db.close();
}
```

XML File: res/menu/menu_settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
<item
    android:id="@+id/add"
    android:icon="@drawable/good"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item
    android:id="@+id/remove"
    android:icon="@drawable/bad"
    android:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest way is to just provide two different buttons and hide/show them accordingly:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuInflater inf = new MenuInflater(this);
  inf.inflate(R.menu.menu_xml, menu);
  return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  MenuItem fave = menu.findItem(R.id.favorite);
  MenuItem unfave = menu.findItem(R.id.unfavorite);

  fave.setVisible(!isFave);
  unfave.setVisible(isFave);
  return true;
}
```

Then you invalidate the options menu when the state has changed. Note that you have to have a global variable that has the current state of the item (where `isFave` is coming from)

```
invalidateOptionsMenu();
```

Comment: Will I need to make my own xml file for the menu items?

Comment: Not necessarily, you can do it the way you've been doing it, instead of inflating it create it on the fly. That said, the xml is much cleaner.

Comment: Trying to use your solution. What method should have my database logic? I find it easier creating menu's using java rather than xml.

Comment: Hmmmm I would move your db code to your `onCreate`, which runs before `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, if I'm not mistaken. Save the record information in a class variable so you can use it in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`.

Comment: Got it working using your solution! I've added the database logic to `onOptionItemSelected()` method. I am using ActionBarSherlock. Do you know if `invalidateOptionsMenu()` works on Froyo and Gingerbread?

Answer (score 1):

Make the isInFavourite variable a global field (declare it outside of the method, just in the class). Any local variables must be final for a scope below them to use them. However, if you make it global, and declare it above, it doesn't need to be final.